# Notepad ++ xml line move up rows

Tags: notepad++, xml

How do I change the order mixed up, Notepad ++ xml file.
`FO_KEP>` change to `OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>`,
Unfortunately, the ctrl + shift + down is not good because I have 3500 `TERMEK>`.

"before"

`<TERMEK>
<TERMEK_KOD>01008213</TERMEK_KOD>
<FO_KEP>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/obrazky/01008213.jpg</FO_KEP>
<OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/dokumenty/Vratko_montazny_navod.jpg</OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>
<OBRAZKY>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/2341000/2341428/245320712.jpg</OBRAZKY>
</TERMEK>`

"after"

`<TERMEK>
<TERMEK_KOD>01008213</TERMEK_KOD>
<OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/dokumenty/Vratko_montazny_navod.jpg</OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>
<FO_KEP>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/obrazky/01008213.jpg</FO_KEP>
<OBRAZKY>https://www.temponabytok.sk/Files/2341000/2341428/245320712.jpg</OBRAZKY>
</TERMEK>`

Comment: I can't tell what you are asking. Can you please [edit] your question to include some kind of "before" and "after" state? Then we might be able to help you figure out how to automate making that change.

Comment: Please [edit] and add text samples (not images) for before and after so we can use then for testing.

Comment: texts are supposed to be copy and paste, not as an image http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: bocsánat de ha beillesztem szöveg ként vagy megjegyzés ként akkor elvesziti a <>>< ben lévő karaktereket.
de köszönöm hogy foglalkoztok vele.

Comment: after inserting the text you can format it as code (select it and press CTRL+K), so you won't loose any characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with find and replace:

- open find and replace dialog (CTRL+H)
- check "regular expression"
- find what:
  `(<FO_KEP>[^<]*<\/FO_KEP>)\r?\n(<OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>[^<]*<\/OSSZESZERELESI_KEP>)`
- replace to:
  `\2\n\1`
- Press "replace all"

You can test the expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/WzO1v5/1).

Comment: I'm happy it helped! if it solved your problem, then please accept it as an answer.